# Formatting in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a column formatting issue:

```
from math import sqrt
n = raw_input("Example Number? ")
n = float(n)
sqaureRootOfN = sqrt(n)

print '-'*50
print ' # of Decimals', '\t', 'New Root', '\t', 'Percent error'
print '-'*50
for a in range(0,10):
    preRoot = float(int(sqaureRootOfN * 10**a))
    newRoot = preRoot/10**a
    percentError = (n - newRoot**2)/n*100
    print ' ', a, '\t\t', newRoot, '\t\t', percentError, '%'
```

It comes out like:

[image]

Not in the same column!?!

Comment: That's because you are putting in two tabs rather than one. Myself I think I'd build each line up in a string and in between adding each number add the appropriate amount of padding as spaces.

Comment: use python string format methods, `format` or `%`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@Bjorn has the right answer here, using the String.format specification. Python's string formatter has really powerful methods for aligning things properly. Here's an example:

```
from math import sqrt
n = raw_input("Example Number? ")
n = float(n)
sqaureRootOfN = sqrt(n)

print '-'*75
print ' # of Decimals', ' ' * 8, 'New Root', ' ' * 10, 'Percent error'
print '-'*75
for a in range(0,10):
    preRoot = float(int(sqaureRootOfN * 10**a))
    newRoot = preRoot/10**a
    percentError = (n - newRoot**2)/n*100
    print " {: <20}{: <25}{: <18}".format(a, newRoot, str(percentError) + ' %')
```

Note that instead of tabs I'm using spaces to space things out. This is because tabs are *really* not what you want to use here, because the rules for how tabs space things are inconsistent (and depend on what your terminal/viewer settings are).

This is what the answer looks like:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 # of Decimals          New Root            Percent error
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0                   9.0                      18.1818181818 %   
 1                   9.9                      1.0 %             
 2                   9.94                     0.198383838384 %  
 3                   9.949                    0.0175747474747 % 
 4                   9.9498                   0.00149490909092 %
 5                   9.94987                  8.7861717162e-05 %
 6                   9.949874                 7.45871112931e-06 %
 7                   9.9498743                1.4284843602e-06 %
 8                   9.94987437               2.14314187048e-08 %
 9                   9.949874371              1.33066711409e-09 %
```

Comment: That's because you're using python 2.6. This question specifically talks about 2.7. Stop downvoting for no good reason.

Comment: simple for me to understand and I like it.

Answer (score 3):

Using [str.format](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax),

```
import math
n = float(raw_input("Example Number? "))
squareRootOfN = math.sqrt(n)

print('''\
{dashes}
{d:<16}{r:<15}{p:<}
{dashes}'''.format(dashes = '-'*50, d = ' # of Decimals', r = 'New Root', p = 'Percent error'))
for a in range(0,10):
    preRoot = float(int(squareRootOfN * 10**a))
    newRoot = preRoot/10**a
    percentError = (n - newRoot**2)/n
    print('  {d:<14}{r:<15}{p:13.9%}'.format(d = a, r = newRoot, p = percentError))
```

yields

```
--------------------------------------------------
 # of Decimals  New Root       Percent error
--------------------------------------------------    
  0             9.0            18.181818182%
  1             9.9             1.000000000%
  2             9.94            0.198383838%
  3             9.949           0.017574747%
  4             9.9498          0.001494909%
  5             9.94987         0.000087862%
  6             9.949874        0.000007459%
  7             9.9498743       0.000001428%
  8             9.94987437      0.000000021%
  9             9.949874371     0.000000001%
```

A few tricks/niceties:

- Instead of three print statements, you can use one print statement on
  a multiline string.
- The percent symbol in the format `{p:13.9%}` lets you leave
  `percentError` as a decimal (without multiplication by 100) and it
  places the `%` at the end for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is how tabs work. To get a correct formatting, you should use [`string.format`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format). For your example, it could look like this:

```
print "{0:2d}          {1:9.8f} {2:f} %".format(a, newRoot, percentError)
```

Comment: That doesn't give the desired output. The values in the New Root column all have the same number of decimal places output.

Comment: `"{0:2d} {1:20.8f} {2:f} %".format` prints the same and you do not mix literal spacing with format spacing

Comment: "{0:2d} {1:20.8f} {2:f} %".format : Does Not seem to work for 2.7